# Working with org footnotes

Tags: org-mode

I have the following code but do not understand how it affects the display of footnotes.  When viewing in org-mode I only see a difference in the tag used to show the footnote marker (e.g. )

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  ;; Set the typeface attributes when displaying footnotes.
  (set-face-attribute 'org-footnote nil
     :height 0.8 :width 'expanded
     :weight 'normal :slant 'italic :underline 'nil
     :foreground "#ae6029" :background "black"))
```

I have done the following example

```
This is a paragraph of text containing a footnote.[fn:1]

[fn:1] This is the content of the footnote. It provides additional information
or references related to the main text.
```

Have read that when one exports an Org document to formats like `HTML` or `LaTeX`, the footnotes will be rendered accordingly, typically as numbered or symbolized markers in the main text, with the corresponding footnote content displayed at the bottom of the page or in a separate section.

Would somebody be so kind to show me an example of a footnote and how to export the org document to `html` and `latex` ?

Comment: Have you read the Org mode manual? Particularly the section on [Footnotes](https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-Footnotes.html) and the chapter on [Exporting](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting.html)? If not, that's where you should start.

Comment: A difficulty with the manual is that there are hardly any examples.  And it is designed that way.  Yet ther are not really other documents except the tutorial which is very basic.

Comment: How would a simple org file with latex commands (e.g. a mathematical equation look like).  I know how to write `tex` and `latex` documents but not doing so from `org-mode`.